# How get a Map<String, List<Object>> from a Stream in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the next class:

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    
    private String title;
    private String codeResponse;
    private String fileName;
}
```

I need to generate a map in which the key is the filename, and the value is the list of objects that contain that filename. I did the following:

```java
Map<String, List<ExampleClass>> mapValues = items
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                item -> item.getFileName(), 
                Collectors.mapping(item -> item, Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

But in this case I am saving in each `fileName` the total list of objects, including those that do not apply.

Comment: remove `Collectors.mapping`. groupingBy + toList will do your task

Comment: How come _in this case I am saving in each fileName the total list of objects, including those that do not apply_?  This does not seem to be reproducible and a list of `ExampleClass` instances with the same `fileName` is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is `Collectors.groupingBy`.  The instances will be placed in a list by default.

```
Map<String, List<ExampleClass>> mapValues = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item->item.getFileName()));
```

You could also use `ExampleClass::getFileName` in place of the lambda.  But that is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thank you so much!